# Mail to SMTP Server via Exchange

Tags: smtp, exchange-2010

The title already says much;
I want to send mails with an adress ( test@something.com ) 
Until we got our Exchange-Server, we were recieving via POP and sending via SMTP.
The office (4 People) wants still to recieve and send with this E-Mail.
The recieve is easy to solve with the POP-Connector that distributes the mails to the accounts, but how about sending? (All mails should go via Exchange-Server but with source adress: test@something.com)

Comment: I'd also turf the POP accounts if you have the option (have control over something.com's MX records) and send mail directly to Exchange.

Comment: @gravyface The problem ist that the current mail address is known and thy don't want to change...

Comment: It doesn't have to change: instead of using POP3 protocol to pull your mail from a third-party into your mail server, reduce complexity by having the MX records point to Exchange (well, point to an A record that resolves to the IP address that Exchange is behind/using) and receive mail with SMTP, not just send it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create a mailbox on the Exchange server with that address as the primary SMTP address. Then give the users SendAs privileges to that mailbox. When sending a message, they can pick this mailbox from the menu next to "From" on the new message.

Comment: How can I add a mailbox with an adress that hasn't the ending @something.local ?

Comment: @heysamhey you need to make Exchange authoritative for your domain.  I suggest you read up on Exchange fundamentals; there's quite a bit to running your own Exchange (mail) server; you might be better off with a hosted solution.